# Remap/Create Virtual Directory for Project folder with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am getting following message while opening my project in Web Application.

> The Web project 'MyProjectName' is currently configured to use the URL
>   'http://localhost/ProjectName'. The Web server has this URL mapped to
>   a different folder 'Physicalpath of the project'. Would you like to
>   remap this URL to point to this Web project's folder?

Any Idea how to disable/enable this message ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

a) either update the url of the project and create a new virtual directory for the project

or

b) update the path of the site that you have already configured by navigating to inetmgr and then updating the path to the new location

Comment: earlier it was asking me to create the virtual directory and now all of the sudden it is asking me to do remap? I mean later on is a better option instead to change the path in IIS manually. I want to know where are these provisions to select unselect ?

Comment: it is asking you to do a remap because in your current project configuration the project url is set to an url that is mapped to a different path.. this happens if you copy your project from one folder to another or if you store the project Url as part of the csproj

Comment: you can update it by right clicking on the web project of your solution select properties and navigate to the Web tab and update the project url settings and save it

Comment: In know we have the provision. My question is, **earlier it was asking me to create the virtual directory and now all of the sudden it is asking me to do remap** Where can we see these options ?